# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code

I tried this:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

It said that the requirement was satisfied.

Then I used:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\arush\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\arush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-komi1sg9\\mysql-connector-python-rf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\arush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-komi1sg9\\mysql-connector-python-rf\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\arush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ov8jdz89\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\arush\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\mysql-connector-python-rf'
         cwd: C:\Users\arush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-komi1sg9\mysql-connector-python-rf\    
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\arush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-komi1sg9\\mysql-connector-nizedpython-rf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\arush\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-komi1sg9\\mysql-connector-python-rappdata\local\programs\python\pythonf\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fiv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\arush\\AppDatle__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.clo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Use();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --rconnector-python-rf\\setup.py'"'"';fecord 'C:\Users\arush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ov8jdz89\in).replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'stall-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compilestall --record 'C:\Users\arush\AppDa --install-headers 'c:\users\arush\appdata\local\programs\pythoversion-externally-managed --compilen\python37\Include\mysql-connector-python-rf' Check the logs fon\python37\Include\mysql-connector-pr full command output.
```

Comment: Have you followed the installation guide? I.e. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html

Comment: @max muster sorry for the inconvenience, i am new here... and yeah i installed it correctly... it worked too but today it's not working... some solutions said mysql.py named file can cause error... and i made a file named that.

Comment: what python version, and what mysql version ?

Comment: Why don't you pip install pymysql or cymysql instead?

Comment: python 3.7.7  mysql 8.0.20

Answer (score 1):

You may be using python three instead. Try `pip3` instead of `pip` when installing via the terminal

Comment: i am using python 3.7.7
i tried it.. it did nothing

Comment: if it states the requirement is already satisfied then that means it should work given you downloaded it to the correct version. Last guess when you run the program to run it as, "python3 program.py", where program is your file name

Comment: it got corrected... by uninstalling the connector then changing file name ... and reinstalling it... thanks for your tries btw

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to answer this question without getting some additional background information. For instance, are you windows? Is your pip updated? Did you install Python from anaconda? DO you have multiple versions of Python installed?

I would have thought a "requirement already satisfied" means you have the file install somewhere.

On Anaconda command prompt, you can type "conda list" to know exactly what you have installed already. Anaconda also has a useful GUI that lists exactly what is there as well

Comment: yeah i am using Window 10.. yep i updated it with a command 
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
I installed python from its official website and i use VScode, i had 2 versions 3.7.7 and 3.8.0 i uninstalled 3.8.0 as it was having issues for installing connector for python... 
(sorry for bad english)